# Advanced css/html table styling

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to achieve table similar to this using css/html only. Is it possible ?

[image]

So the white area is the `places` table. This is the HTML for the table :

```
<table class="places">
    <tr>
        <td class="solid">K</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="solid">P</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="solid">25</td>
        <td class="solid">26</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="solid">47</td>
        <td class="solid">48</td>
    </tr>

    (...)

</table>
```

And my css :

```
.places{
    position:relative;
    background:white;
    width:160px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    padding:5px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
    .places tr {
    }
        .places td {
            width:22px;
            height:22px;
            text-align:center;
        }
            .solid {
                border: 1px solid #d2cdd1;
                border-top:none;
                background-color:#e7e7e7;
                text-align:center;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
```

I was pretty sure, that although tables are a bit different than other html objects, padding should work here. But it looks that I was wrong. Cellspacing/cellpading have no effect. Currently I was able to get something looking like this :

[image]

Comment: should I forget about tables and do it with unordered ilsts ?

Comment: You should consider that if your list is erm... a list, and not tabular data. We can't really tell right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `border-spacing` property.

Table cells are *not* like other elements, because while `div` and `p` gets are block level elements, and `span` and `input` are inline, table cells and rows get their own `table-cell` and `table-row` display values.

Using `border-spacing` with `border-collapse: separate` will give you what you'd need. Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/kjag3/1/

PS. I've also taken the liberty of cleaning up the HTML by separating them into two tables, so you won't need the fillers for the empty cells.

Comment: of course dumb ie cannot handle this. Oh well, maybe next gen will :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't set any spacing between the cells is that you have `border-collapse` set to `collapse` in the styles for your `table`.  If you use `border-collapse:separate` instead, you should be able to add margins to your table cells and put spacing between them.

Using `border-collapse:collapse` makes it so that adjacent table cells use the same border; naturally, you wouldn't be able to put space between two elements when they're attached to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether a table structure is appropriate for what you're trying to achieve?

To me, it looks like the 'K' and 'P' are headings, and the gap between the 'K' and 'P' numbers suggests that 'K' and 'P' are separate and shouldn't be part of the same table. So I suggest getting rid of the table and restructuring your HTML to use simple headings and `div` tags like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="places">
    <h2>K</h2>
    <div>25</div>
    <div>26</div>
    <div>23</div>
    <div>24</div>
    <div>21</div>
    <div>22</div>
</div>

<div class="places">
    <h2>P</h2>
    <div>47</div>
    <div>48</div>
    <div>45</div>
    <div>46</div>
    <div>43</div>
    <div>44</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.places {
    width: 55px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 25px 0 0;

}

.places h2, .places div {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
    border: 1px solid #d2cdd1;
    border-top:none;
    background-color:#e7e7e7;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.places div {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: If you really want to get picky, then the `div`s should probably be an unordered list.